# NGINX rewrite IP to Domain Name

Tags: apache, nginx, vps, centos7, plesk

Server Setup:

1. VPS
2. Plesk 12.5
3. Centos 7
4. NGINX as reverse proxy to Apache 2.4
5. Path to NGINX config: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Plesk provides a GUI Apache & nginx Settings dialog box, but is unable to accept server{} blocks from there.

I've tried the following, and several variations thereof, without success:

```
server {
  server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;
  return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri 
}
```

Here's another example of what we are trying to do and need to know where to place the code so NGINX reads and honors the instruction for execution.

```
server {
server_name newdomain.com www.newdomain.com;

# ngx_pagespeed & ngx_pagespeed handler
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeed.conf;
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeedhandler.conf;
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeedstatslog.conf;

# limit_conn limit_per_ip 16;
# ssi  on;

access_log /home/nginx/domains/newdomain.com/log/access.log combined    buffer=32k;
error_log /home/nginx/domains/newdomain.com/log/error.log;

root /home/nginx/domains/newdomain.com/public;

location / {

# block common exploits, sql injections etc
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/block.conf;

# Enables directory listings when index file not found
#autoindex  on;

 }

 location /forums {
 try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~^(/forums/page/).*(\.php)$ {
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

# Mask fake admin directory
location ~^/forums/admin/(.*)$ {
    deny     all;
}

# Secure real admin directory
location ~^(/forums/mynewadmin/).*(\.php) {
    #allow         127.0.0.1;
    #deny          all;
    #auth_basic    "Restricted Area";
    #auth_basic_user_file $document_root/forums/mynewadmin/.htpasswd;
 include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
}

# IP.Board PHP/CGI Protection
location ~^(/forums/uploads/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/hooks/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/cache/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/screenshots/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/downloads/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/blog/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/public/style_).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}

include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf;
}
```

Where do I need to place this or similar directing in this scenario to direct all direct IP traffic to the domain name? I've tried placing the snippet in various NGINX config files so far without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add this into Nginx's "additional directives" in UI:

```
location /forums {
 try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~^(/forums/page/).*(\.php)$ {
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

# Mask fake admin directory
location ~^/forums/admin/(.*)$ {
    deny     all;
}

# IP.Board PHP/CGI Protection
location ~^(/forums/uploads/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/hooks/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/cache/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/screenshots/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/downloads/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/blog/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/forums/public/style_).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
```

I've ignore all system-wide and commented settings. Also you can try to add content from

```
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
```

Pay attention that your web site root is placed into `/httpdocs` folder, according to this config I've see that you web root was in `public` directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way is to set `default domain` for IP `xx.xx.xx.xx` to `domain.com` in `Tools & Settings > IP addreses > xx.xx.xx.xx`

Also you can create `.htaccess` file in web root of `domain.com` with content:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

**Why it does not work via Additional directives?**

- plesk include custom directives inside of nginx domain's server{} - so server inside server is not possible. It's by design.
- custom directives includinв at the end of nginx domain's server{} so if request was catch by some upper rule or location all other will be ignored for this request.

Comment: Thanks. I would love to use .htaccess, but those rules don't seem to take when using NGINX as a reverse proxy to Apache. Here is some additional information as to my current setup:

PHP hander is currently set to PHP-FPM application by NGINX. We've also tried PHP-FPM application by Apache but did not see the behavior change at all.

Are you saying that by setting the default domain for IP as you described above will allow us to use .htaccess in lieu of NGINX directives?

Comment: When you set "default domain" for IP you don't need any additional rules/action, because Plesk adds this IP as "listen xx.xx.xx.xx" to your domain's config. So your domain will be available directly by IP too.

Comment: Thanks. See above for additional example of what we need to do. Thanks.